# Jenkins: Logs are not being written in jenkins.log file

Tags: jenkins, logging

Jenkins: Logs from jenkins (System log -> All Jenkins logs) are not reflected in the jenkins.log or slave.log files. How can I fix this?

Comment: update: I found the way^^ use this tutorial https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003914391-How-to-change-the-default-or-package-log-levels

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If anyone will have this issue, you can try finding the config.xml file of the specific job from VM, copy the file and then enable the job log logger for the job from UI, and see what changes in the config file: I found out that this part is added:

 <buildWrappers>
    <org.jenkins.ci.plugins.jobloglogger.JobLogLoggerBuildWrapper plugin=job-log-logger-plugin@1.0>
        <suppressEmpty>true</suppressEmpty?
</org.jenkins.ci.plugins.jobLogLogger.JobLogLoggerBuildWrapper>
</buildWrappers>

So you may use this to automate the process for all the jobs.